# Proving $P[\{X_n ≤ x\} ∩ \{|X_n − X| < \epsilon\}] \leq P[X ≤ x + \epsilon]$

Tags: probability, random-variables

I'm studying Theorem 5.2.1 from Hogg, Craig Introduction to Mathematical Statistics 8th Edition. I'm adding a few intermediate steps to the proof for clarity and want to know if I'm doing it correctly. Thanks in advance!

My goal is to prove:

$P[\{X_n ≤ x\} ∩ \{|X_n − X| < \epsilon\}] \leq P[X ≤ x + \epsilon]$

where $X_n$ is a sequence of random variables.

My attempt:

$P[\{X_n ≤ x\} ∩ \{|X_n − X| < \epsilon\}]$

$= P[\{X_n ≤ x\} \cap (\{X_n − X < \epsilon\} \cup \{X \lt X_n + \epsilon\} )]$

$= P[(\{X_n ≤ x\} \cap (\{X_n − X < \epsilon\}) \cup (\{X_n ≤ x\} \cap \{X \lt X_n + \epsilon\})]$

$\leq P[\{X_n ≤ x\} \cap \{X \lt X_n + \epsilon\}]$

$=P[X \lt x + \epsilon]$

$\leq P[X \leq x + \epsilon]$

Comment: Lines 3 to 4 and 4 to 5 are both wrong.

Comment: At first impression, I am not convinced by the first inequality you use. To prove the assertion, argue by contradiction. Assume $\omega \in \{|X_n-X|<\varepsilon\}\cap \{X_n\leq x\}$ but $\omega \notin \{X\leq x+\varepsilon\}$. Then, $X(\omega)>x+\varepsilon$. But this would imply $|X(\omega)-X_n(\omega)|=X(\omega)-X_n(\omega)\geq \varepsilon$ which contradicts our assumption.

Comment: Forget about probabilities and random variables, and prove that if $|u-v|<a$ and $v\le b$ then $u<a+b.$

Comment: @Snoop Your argument convinced me. I think the first line of my proof is wrong. It shouldn't be union but intersection. $= P[\{X_n ≤ x\} \cap \{X_n − X < \epsilon\} \cap \{X \lt X_n + \epsilon\}]$. Then using Bonferroni’s inequality from it follows $\leq P[\{X_n ≤ x\} \cap \{X \lt X_n + \epsilon\}]$. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$
X_n\leqslant x\implies X_n+\epsilon \leqslant x+\epsilon \implies X_n+|X-X_n|\leqslant x+\epsilon \implies X\leqslant x+\epsilon 
$$
Now, as a probability measure is an increasing function, we have that

$$
\{X_n\leqslant x\}\subset \{X\leqslant x+\epsilon \}\implies P(X_n\leqslant x)\leqslant P(X\leqslant x+\epsilon )
$$

∎